# android tablelayout, column pushing other columns to the right when entered a lenghy text

Tags: android

I am having a problem working with TableLayout. I will explain with the help of screeshots.

I've created the first two rows, each containing two columns.

[image]

Then I add the third row which contains only one column, and when I add a lengthy text to that column, it pushes the column 2 of first two rows to the right.

[image]

Someone please help me on how to fix it. Regards

here's the code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.cinch.gogch.activities.EmergencyProfileCardActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView android:text="Emergency Profile Card"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/home_container_shape"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/emailTextView"
                android:text="sarath@cinplc.com"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                />
            <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="3">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/dobLabelTextView"
                    android:text="DOB: "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/dobTextView"
                    android:text="29/06/1991"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="5">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/genTextView"
                    android:text="Gender: "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/genderTextView"
                    android:text="Male"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/socialTextView"
                    android:text="SSN: "
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/ssnTextView"
                    android:text="123-42-1412"
                    android:textColor="#000000"

                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingTop="2dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/addressTextView"
                android:text="Akkoor, Sakthikulangara, Kollam"
                android:textColor="#000000"

                />
        </TableRow>


        </TableLayout>/>



</LinearLayout>
```

If I enter very lengthy text in the third row, this is what it looks like

[image]

Comment: please add a scrrenshot of what you expect?

Comment: @KarthikaPB I've edited my post, please see. hope you understand my problem now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try to changee the third row like this



<TableRow
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:weightSum="2"  
            >

            <TextView
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/addressTextView"
                android:text="Akkoor, Sakthikulangara, Kollam"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                />
           <View 
              android:layout_height="10dp"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="1"

              />
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: Many thanks, with some modifications, i finally got what I was looking for.